# Get dataTable data using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, datatable

I am trying to display dataTable data using ajax but it didn't work.

This is my jquery code :

```
$('#example').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'data.php',
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $("#tbody_example").html(msg);
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is my data.php page :

```
    <?php   echo '<td>Name</td>
            <td>Position</td>
            <td>Office</td>
            <td>Extn.</td>
            <td>Start date</td>
            <td>Salary</td>'; ?>
```

and This is my dataTable :

```
 <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_example">

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

My dataTable still empty and I get MOCK GET: data.php as error.
Any one can help me.

Answer (score 1):

That will not work.

Please, reference [DataTables documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) to see that `success` must *not* be overridden as it is used internally in DataTables.

Instead you might use `function ajax( data, callback, settings )`

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: function(data, callback, settings) {
        $.get({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'data.php',
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#tbody_example").html(msg); // this is NOT how the table should be populated

                // invoke callback(msg) to populate the table
            });
    }
});
```

Thus, you populate the table by calling `callback(response_data)` with the `response_data` that is either `string[][]` or `object[]` type. In case of the latter you might need to add [`"columns"` property](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns) to DataTables config.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.I just add dataType

```
                ajax: {
                   type: 'GET',
                   url: 'data.php',
                   dataType : 'html',
                   success: function (msg) {
                      $("#tbody_datatable").html(msg);

                    },
                    error: function (req, status, err) {
                         console.log('Something went wrong', status, err);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the below thing, It should work

In php file

```
$content = "<td>Name</td>
            <td>Position</td>
            <td>Office</td>
            <td>Extn.</td>
            <td>Start date</td>
            <td>Salary</td>";

$return["json"] = json_encode();
echo json_encode($return);
```

In ajax

```
ajax: {
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'data.php',
         success: function (msg) {
               $("#tbody_example").html(msg["json"]);
         }
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Wrapping a lump of HTML in JSON is pointless if a lump of HTML is all you are sending back … and you got the PHP hopelessly wrong in your attempt to do that anyway so your example will not work.